# change css of element depending on current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm currently working on a slider for a website.

This slider has three components.

- Game list
- Team overview
- Awards

I have all games displayed at the same time, but only want the one corresponding to the current team be highlighted. The amount of games displayed is equal to the amount of teams and game[0] belongs to team[0] and so on.

**EDIT** I've changed the slider a bit :)

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');

[].forEach.call(slides, function (s) {
    var next = s.getElementsByClassName('next')[0],
        prev = s.getElementsByClassName('prev')[0],
        inner = s.getElementsByClassName('inner')[0],
        slides = inner.getElementsByClassName('slide'),
        currentTeamIndex = 0,
        width = 1344;

    var $gameList = $('#gameList'),
        $gameContainer = $gameList.find('.slides'),
        $game = $gameContainer.find('.slide');

    function switchSlide() {
        inner.style.left = -width * currentTeamIndex + 'px';

    }

    next.addEventListener('click', function () {
        currentTeamIndex++;

        if (currentTeamIndex >= slides.length) {
        currentTeamIndex = 0;
        }

        switchSlide();
    });

    prev.addEventListener('click', function () {
        currentTeamIndex--;

        if (currentTeamIndex < 0) {
            currentTeamIndex = slides.length - 1;
        }

        switchSlide();
    });

});
```

How can I do that? I'm fairly new to javascript and jQuery.

Comment: If it is highlighted or not is made trough the `is-active` class?

Comment: Yes. The default look has an opacity of .5 and `is-active` resets it to 1.

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle / codepen? I think it would be way easier to help you that way

Comment: I've tried my best with jsfiddle xD https://jsfiddle.net/zq8r2gzm/1/